# How do convert prices on my page between currencies?

Tags: money

I have a website which sells Hotels in UK and USA to Clients in Germany. I am looking for a way to automatically convert US$ and UK£ automatically in EURO.

I managed to do this through http://dynamicconverter.com/.

However this only works when you have either UK hotels OR USA hotels on a single page. It does not work when both $ and £ are present on a single page. It simply takes all currency as either $ or £.

Does anyone know of a system which can detect different currencies on the same webpage and convert them?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use one of the APIs that allow currency conversion. Here's a topic from Stack Exchange that gives you a nice set of resources to start with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391430/2028547

Answer (score 2):

I am the webmaster at coinmill.com.   I have various ways for webmasters to show converted prices on their websites.   There are examples here: http://coinmill.com/webmaster_options.html

I'm not sure what you mean by "automatically detect", but tools from coinmill.com can be used to convert different currencies within the same page.